# Is there a way to configure traceroute such that the -T or -I flags do not require root privs to perform?

Tags: linux, centos, traceroute

I am using Centos 7. Basically I just want any user to be able to do a ICMP or TCP traceroute. Is there a way to configure `traceroute` such that the `-T` or `-I` flags do not require root privilegess to perform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Kubuntu `traceroute` does not allow regular users to use `-T` or `-I` either. `/usr/bin/traceroute` is a symlink and eventually it points to `/usr/bin/traceroute.db` which looks like this:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/traceroute.db
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 68768 Aug 29  2016 /usr/bin/traceroute.db
$ getcap /usr/bin/traceroute.db
$   # empty
$
```

To achieve what you want, this works for me:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw+eip /path/to/traceroute_regular_file
```

For completeness, this is how to revert:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw-eip /path/to/traceroute_regular_file
```

`setcap` doesn't resolve symlinks, that's why you need to find the regular file. In my case it's `/usr/bin/traceroute.db`; I don't know CentOS enough to tell if there are symlinks involved. Investigate.

If I were you, I would try `setcap` on a copy first (the target filesystem must support extended attributes). I would alter the system-wide file only after I confirmed the copy works as expected.

Note a system upgrade that replaces the executable will most likely ignore the extra capability of the old file while creating a new one. When a new file replaces the old one, `traceroute` will effectively lose the capability.

---

In general the solution is somewhat explained here: [**How to set capabilities with `setcap` command?**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389903/108618) And there is [`man 7 capabilities`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html):

> Starting with kernel 2.2, Linux divides the privileges traditionally associated with superuser into distinct units, known as capabilities, which can be independently enabled and disabled. Capabilities are a per-thread attribute.
>
> […]
>
> `CAP_NET_RAW`
>
> - Use RAW and PACKET sockets;
> - bind to any address for transparent proxying.
>
> […]
>
> Since kernel 2.6.24, the kernel supports associating capability sets with an executable file using `setcap(8)`. The file capability sets are stored in an extended attribute (see `setxattr(2)` and `xattr(7)`) named `security.capability`. […]