# How to allow `iw dev link` as non-root user?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, permissions, arch-linux

I have a laptop and desktop, both running Arch linux. On the laptop, I can run (as a non-root user):

```
iw dev wlp3s0 link
```

This outputs all the expected information.

On the desktop, running the same command gives the SSID and frequency, followed by

```
command failed: Operation not permitted (-1)
```

I suspected that this was because the laptop was set up to allow sudo access without a password, but adding that on the desktop didn't fix it.

Running the same command as root on the desktop (or with sudo) works as expected.

What sort of configuration am I missing on the desktop here?

Comment: I realise I can write a shell script which executes "sudo iw" for me and alias that, however that's not solving the underlying problem.

Comment: I don't know what happens but *maybe* [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1545006/432690) can lead to *some* solution.